# PHP Array - how to save a few lines for matching a long list of characters

Tags: php, arrays

I got a question when I was doing some Array in PHP.
I don't know how to write the code for the following case:

```
$arrs = array("a@c", "cr", "exd", "hello", "gg%j", "hwa", "@", "8");

foreach ($arrs as $arr){
// if $arr does not belong to any characters from a to z, 
// then there must be some special character in it.
// Say for example, "a@c" will still be regarded as fine string, 
// since it contains normal characters a and c.
// another example, "gg%j" will also be fine, since it contains g and j.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex, and the [**`preg_match`**][1] function :

```
$arrs = array("abc", "cr", "exd", "hello", "gj", "hwa", "@", "8");
foreach ($arrs as $arr){
    // if $arr does not belong to any characters from a to z, 
    // then there must be some special character in it.
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/', $arr)) {
        var_dump($arr);
    }
}
```

Which would get you the following output :

```
string '@' (length=1)
string '8' (length=1)
```

Here, the regex is matching :

- beginning of string : `^`
- any number of characters between `a` and `z` : `[a-z]*`
- end of string : `$`

So, if the string contains anything that's not between `a` and `z`, it will not match ; and `var_dump` the string.
[1]: https://www.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrs = array("abc", "cr", "exd", "hello", "gj", "hwa", "@", "8");

foreach ($arrs as $arr){
// if $arr does not belong to any characters from a to z, 
// then there must be some special character in it.
   if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]+/",$arr)==0)
   {
       echo "There must be a special character in it.";
   }
}
```

This sounds suspiciously like a homework question...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-z]*$/", $arr)) {
    // $arr has something other than just a to z in it
}
```